# extend asp.net repeater, writing c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to extend repeater control to add pagination. I started with creating control which derives from Repeater but there is a problem:

```
public partial class controls_pagination : Repeater
```

> Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

That should I do to make it work ?

Comment: You need to create web user control or custom control. Take a look at MSDN resource.

Comment: But I created one and I want to extend Repeater instead of writing completely new one

Answer (score -1):

You can paging repeater using this code. please go through the link :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CollectionPager.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/SQLPager_For_Everything.aspx